# Issue with a query Firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to do a query to obtain the information for displaying a list of followers/following. I am currently getting an error as such: `Could not cast value of type 'FIRDataSnapshot' (0x108967580) to 'NSArray' (0x10b3e3e28).` I am new to firebase and still learning about queries, my query is as follows:

```
if isFollowers == true {
            self.isFollowers = true
            ref = ref.child("followers")
            let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userFollow")
            query.queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    for s in snapshot.children.allObjects.first as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                        print("are we even in here?")
                        let item = s.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>
                        let user = FollowInfoForUser(dictionary: item as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
                        self.userFollowIndex.insert(user, at: 0)
                        print(self.userFollowIndex)
                        //print(self.userFollowIndex.count)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                    }

                } else {

                    print("sorry no followers for you to see")

                }


            })

        }
```

The line of error is as such:

```
for s in snapshot.children.allObjects.first as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
```

my tree is also as follows:

```
-Users
---UserUID
-----Followers
--------FollowAutoChild
----------------userFollow
----------------userFollowKey
```

I am trying to store the FollowAutoChild information

My whole query function code is as follows:

```
func setValues(isFollowers : Bool, isFollowing : Bool, isViewingSelf : Bool, isViewingOther : Bool, key : String) {

        var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

        if isViewingSelf {
            print("we are viewing us")
            ref = ref.child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
        } else
            if isViewingOther {
            print("we are viewing them")
            ref = ref.child(key)

        }


        if isFollowers == true {
            self.isFollowers = true
            ref = ref.child("followers")
            let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userFollow")
            query.queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                    for s in snapshot.children.allObjects.first as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                        print("are we even in here?")
                        let item = s.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>
                        let user = FollowInfoForUser(dictionary: item as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
                        self.userFollowIndex.insert(user, at: 0)
                        print(self.userFollowIndex)
                        //print(self.userFollowIndex.count)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                    }

                } else {

                    print("sorry no followers for you to see")

                }


            })

            }

        }
```

Comment: The error is appearing because you are casting the **first** element of `snapshot.children`, which is just one element(An `FIRDataSnapshot` in this case), as an array of `FIRDataSnapshot`'s. Either cast all the objects as an array of `FIRDatasnapShot`'s, **or** the first one as an `FIRDataSnapshot` but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that!

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Comment: I posted it as an answer so the question can be marked as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is appearing because you are casting the **first** element of `snapshot.children`, which is just one element(An `FIRDataSnapshot` in this case), as an array of `FIRDataSnapshot`'s. Either cast all the objects as an array of `FIRDatasnapShot`'s, **or** the first one as an `FIRDataSnapshot` but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your for_in loop should look like this

```
for s in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    print("are we even in here?")
                    let item = s.value as! [String: AnyObjcet]
                    let user = FollowInfoForUser(dictionary: item)
                    self.userFollowIndex.insert(user, at: 0)
                    print(self.userFollowIndex)
                    //print(self.userFollowIndex.count)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()

                }
```

you are doing wrong casting